# Timer in Android

Tags: java, android, timer

I am planning to create a timer, it is working fine in some cases, but When my current time is 12PM and 12AM its going to 3rd else if block, but in 12 AM it's OK, But for 12Pm it should be at first if,

what should i do, any solution please....

```
try
        {
            current_time= format.parse(current_time_system);

           Toast.makeText(this, current_time_system, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            t_seheritime=format.parse(today_seheritime);
            t_iftartime=format.parse(today_iftartime);
            tmw_seheritime=format.parse(tomorrow_seheritime);
            startday_time=format.parse("00:00:00");
            enddayTime=format.parse("24:00:00");
            Date sptime1=format.parse("12:00:00");
            Date sptime2 =format.parse("12:59:00");

            if(current_time.getTime()>t_seheritime.getTime() && current_time.getTime()<=t_iftartime.getTime())
            {
                status.setText("আজকের ইফতারের সময় বাকি...");
                Toast.makeText(this, today_seheritime+ today_iftartime , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               Toast.makeText(this, "a", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Date1= format.parse(today_iftartime);
                Date2= format.parse(current_time_system);

                millis = Date1.getTime() - Date2.getTime();

            }
            else if (current_time.getTime()>t_iftartime.getTime())
            {
                status.setText("পরবর্তি সাহারীর সময় বাকি...");
                Toast.makeText(this,  t_iftartime.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Toast.makeText(this, "b", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Date1= enddayTime;
                Date2= format.parse(current_time_system);

                millis= ((enddayTime.getTime()-Date2.getTime())+(tmw_seheritime.getTime()-startday_time.getTime()));
            }
             else if( current_time.getTime()>=startday_time.getTime() && current_time.getTime()<=t_seheritime.getTime())
            {
                    status.setText("আজকের সাহারীর সময় বাকি...");
                    Toast.makeText(this, "c", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Date1 = format.parse(today_seheritime);
                    Date2 = format.parse(current_time_system);

                    millis = Date2.getTime() - Date1.getTime();

            }


        }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Problem**

Your **Time** Checking way is wrong .

You should use **[compareTo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)**

> The java.util.Calendar.compareTo() method compares the time values (millisecond offsets) between the Calendar object and anotherCalendar object.

```
if (current_time.getTime().compareTo(t_seheritime.getTime() > 0                        
{

}
```

Read **[compare dates in Java.](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-compare-dates-in-java/)**

Comment: It causes because of this-  
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

hh gives me AM/PM format time, 
HH gives me times in (0-23) hrs format.